# How to get navigated to a new record through url.resolveRecord() in suitescript 2.0?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a clickable sublist field, on clicking, user should be navigated to an employee record in create mode with some field values copied from my custom record to employee rec (as params).

I tried using resolveRecord() API, the existing employee record opens if i put any id, but because i want the same window to be navigated to an new employee record, i cannot know its internal id.

Can anyone guide me what should i do? how would i make this work and how to pass params? I am new in development.

My code:

```
var hyperlink = '<a href ="https://system.eu2.netsuite.com';
    var hyperEnd = '">View</a>';

      sublist.setSublistValue({
        id: 'custpage_view',
        line: 2,
        value: hyperlink + url.resolveRecord({
          recordType: 'employee',
          recordId: whatToPutHere,
          isEditMode: true,
          params:{

          }
        }) + hyperEnd
      });
```

Comment: Hi 4ni5, could you please check my answer and if you're happy with it accept it? If you require more assistance, please let me know.

Comment: i want some fields to be copied from from one rec to another by hitting the button, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ignore the SuiteScript 2.0 API Documentation where it says that the `options.recordId` is *required*, it is not.

**Omit the `recordId` parameter and it will provide a link to a NEW record of the specified `recordType`.**

### Generic example to get a link to a new Employee record:

```
url.resolveRecord({
    recordType: record.Type.EMPLOYEE,
    isEditMode: true,
    params:{}
})
```

### Specific answer to the asked question:

```
var employee_firstname = "John";
var employee_lastname = "Doe";
var employee_phone = "0123456789";

var link_url = url.resolveRecord({
    recordType: record.Type.EMPLOYEE,
    isEditMode: true,
    params: {
        'record.firstname':employee_firstname,
        'record.lastname':employee_lastname,
        'record.phone':employee_phone
    }
});

sublist.setSublistValue({
    id: 'custpage_view',
    line: 2,
    value: '<a target="_blank" href="'+link_url+'">View</a>'
});
```